# Running a single JUnit5 test on gradle exits with STANDARD_ERROR

Tags: java, gradle, junit5, gradlew

The test being run shows passed, but the Gradle Test Executor shows a STANDARD_ERROR.

```
>>./gradlew --stop                                                                                                     
Stopping Daemon(s)
1 Daemon stopped
>>./gradlew test --tests com.tudu.task.TaskListTests.tasksAddedSequentiallyWithDescendingDueDateAreSortedByAscendingDueDate
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 8 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :test

Gradle Test Executor 1 STANDARD_ERROR
Mar 11, 2021 4:53:00 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator lambda$logTestDescriptorExclusionReasons$7
INFO: 0 containers and 1 tests were Method or class mismatch

TaskListTests > tasks added sequentially with descending due date are sorted by ascending due date PASSED
```

This error does not occur when I run the complete test file.

```
>>./gradlew test --tests com.tudu.task.TaskListTests                                                                       

> Task :test

TaskListTests > tasks added sequentially with descending due date are sorted by ascending due date PASSED

TaskListTests > tasks added sequentially with random due date are sorted by ascending due date PASSED
```

What does "Method or class mismatch" mean? What is causing the STANDARD_ERROR?

Answer (score 1):

That `STANDARD_ERROR` is current JUnit 5 behavior: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1774

You could try the workaround here with below `*.properties` example: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1774#issuecomment-463662553

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level=INFO

org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.level=WARNING
```